# Not able to build a solution in Release mode in Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, msbuild, visual-studio-2017

For some reason i'm unable to build a project in Release mode, this is the error i'm getting

```
> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       The "XamlCTask" task failed unexpectedly.
System.InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.

Server stack trace: 
   at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.ReadSymbols(ISymbolReader reader)
   at Mono.Cecil.ModuleReader.ReadSymbols(ModuleDefinition module, ReaderParameters parameters)
   at Mono.Cecil.ModuleReader.CreateModule(Image image, ReaderParameters parameters)
   at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.ReadModule(String fileName, ReaderParameters parameters)
   at Mono.Cecil.AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(String fileName, ReaderParameters parameters)
   at Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.XamlCTask.Execute(IList`1& thrownExceptions)
   at Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.XamlTask.Execute()
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext()
```

Tried everything, updated Xamarin.forms package,deleted bin/obj folders,restarted vs with admin privileges, any inputs would be deeply appreciated as i'm stuck with unable to put apps on production

Comment: Have you tried disabling [XAML Compilation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xamlc)?

Comment: @Andrew I can give it a try, but for the time being i've rolled back to xf version 2.3.4.224 :/ and it seems to work in that version

Comment: Can you rebuild the solution ..than you will get the exact error why it is not building

Comment: @AditKothari the above error is what i'm getting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Not able to build a solution in Release mode in Xamarin forms

Yes, this is a known issue for `Xamarin.Forms`, the workaround for this issue is downgrading `Xamarin.Forms` to `2.3.4.224`.

You can check following thread for some more details:

[Build failed when upgrade Xamarin.Forms to latest version](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/96302/build-failed-when-upgrade-xamarin-forms-to-latest-version)

Besides, if your `Xamarin.Form` version is not compatible/matching with your NuGet package which you have installed, we`d better to update the nuget packages to match the dependencies with NuGet package.

Hope this helps.

Comment: yea, that's what i did

Comment: may not be the ideal solution, but nonetheless does the trick

Answer (score 0):

Please do Following.

1. Uninstall Xamarin.Forms
2. Restart VS
3. Install Xamarin.Forms.
4. Build

It will work for sure.